# Could we extend R/Exams to include the Brightspace LMS?

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm an enthuastic user of R/exams, it's a wonderful system and it has revolutionised my use of our university's LMS. But now we're moving from Moodle to Brightspace. I'm wondering, would it be possible to develop an exams2brightspace() function.

Thanks
Eugene

Importing a question bank in to moodle using exams2moodle() and then exporting the XML file to brightspace works for a limited number of questions, but anything complicated (answer tables, generated images...) gets butchered by the system.

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow - I would contact the maintainers of R/exams and/or Brightspace if I was you.  The literal answer to "would it be possible to develop an exams2brightspace() function." is very likely to be "yes", but that's presumably not what you're after!

Comment: I think this belongs at https://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=4377

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked of the package authors directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R/exams d2l multiple choice question doesn't select correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754415/r-exams-d2l-multiple-choice-question-doesnt-select-correct-answer)

Comment: I have also voted to close this question now, flagging it as a duplicate because there is already another non-conclusive discussion here on StackOverflow (and some related threads on R-Forge). Nevertheless I also wrote an answer here, in case this is useful for the original poster.

Comment: I vote to close my own question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several R/exams users have been working with various workarounds to export their exercises to Brightspace/D2L. None of these were perfect but some were doable but the details changed across Brightspace releases. Also, there was no proper Brightspace documentation that would explain what works and how, so a lot of trial and error was involed.

The most recent discussion here on StackOverflow was this, I think: [R/exams d2l multiple choice question doesn't select correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754415/r-exams-d2l-multiple-choice-question-doesnt-select-correct-answer)

This also includes links to further discussions in our R-Forge forum.

In summary: It should be doable to write a Brightspace/D2L interface but it's not straightforward. I would recommend that you start trying the suggestions from previous threads and then continue the discussion there.